# Deleting all checked out files without affecting SVN repo

Tags: svn, version-control

I am learning to use Subversion and am experimenting. I checked out a copy of a test repo and put it where I don't want it -- and, in fact, I don't want it at all anymore.

I don't want to just delete it -- or is that the thing to do?

Comment: Have you tried to right click on folder --> tortiseSVN --> relocate?

Comment: I believe if you relocate to the same exact path, it will ask you if you would like to remove the folder, avoid checking in.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just delete your complete local checked-out working copy (including all .svn directories).

This will not modify your repository as you are not committing your deletion.

*Note*: If you want to move the local working directory to another location on your harddisk, just move (the top-level) directory to its new location and your local working copy is still working properly (ie the link with your repository is not lost)